# Alternative to virtual templated function

Tags: c++

I currently use a tree structure, made out of subtypes of the `class Node`. The base `Node class` looks something like this:

```
// Base Node Type
class Node
{
public:
    virtual ~Node() = default;

    virtual std::vector<Node*> GetChildren() const = 0;
};
```

Here are some example `Node` subtypes:

```
// First Node Subtype
class NodeOne : public Node
{
public:
    NodeOne(std::unique_ptr<Node>&& t_node)
        : m_Node{ std::move(t_node) }
    {
    }

    virtual ~NodeOne() = default;

    std::vector<Node*> GetChildren() const override
    {
        std::vector<Node*> children{};
        
        AddChildren(children, m_Node);

        return children;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Node> m_Node{};
};
```

This node owns a pointer to another child `Node` (can be null).

```
// Second Node Subtype
class NodeTwo : public Node
{
public: 
    NodeTwo(std::unique_ptr<NodeOne>&& t_leftNode, std::unique_ptr<NodeOne>&& t_rightNode) 
        : m_LeftNode{ std::move(t_leftNode) }, m_RightNode{ std::move(t_rightNode) }
    {
    }

    virtual ~NodeTwo() = default;

    std::vector<Node*> GetChildren() const override
    {
        std::vector<Node*> children{};

        AddChildren(children, m_LeftNode);
        AddChildren(children, m_RightNode);

        return children;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<NodeOne> m_LeftNode{};
    std::unique_ptr<NodeOne> m_RightNode{};
};
```

This node owns a pointer to two child `NodeOne`s (both can be null). As you can see, both implement the pure virtual function `GetChildren()`. This is the implementation of the `AddChildren()` function (it just adds the `Node*` and its `Node*` children to the `std::vector<Node*>`):

```
// AddChildren() Implementation
template<typename T>
void AddChildren(std::vector<Node*>& t_vec, const std::unique_ptr<T>& t_child)
{
    if (!t_child)
        return;

    auto children{ t_child->GetChildren() };
    t_vec.insert(t_vec.end(), children.begin(), children.end());
    t_vec.push_back(t_child.get());
}
```

I recently noticed, getting children of all `Node` subtypes from `GetChildren()` is not what I actually want most of the time. I often need children of just one specific interface or type. I wanted to achieve this by making the `GetChildren()` function a `template<>`, and then in `AddChildren()` I would only add a `Node*` to the `std::vector<Node*>` if it is of that type (with a constexpr if statement or something similiar). I just found out that `template<>` on a `virtual` function is not allowed in C++. Is there any way I could `GetChildren()` of only one type (I don't want to use `RTTI` so I would prefer a compile time solution).

Comment: If you must exclude RTTI then you only have one option: implement a separate method for each such subclass. Those are the only two options available in C++, there are no other possibilities. The exact mechanism and the approach depends on the details which you did not include (whether the children of a different node are still searched, and the same node children get included, or not), there are multiple ways to implement this, so no authoritative answer is possible.

Comment: Yes, if i GetChildren() on a node, it should recursively call GetChildren() on all its children, 
and return children and their children etc.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik and thats pretty unfortunate, but I actually don't think it being non-virtual will be a big problem for me. Is there any way I can force every subtype to implement it without being virtual ?

Comment: @SamoChreno I would just do it the straightforward way.  The overhead for calling a `virtual` function is not that big.

Comment: Nope, C++ does not work this way. There are no workarounds to the fact that there are no virtual template functions. `Node` must implement `getNodeOneChildren()`, `getNodeTwoChildren()`, each subclass must implement `getChildren()` by calling the right one. The default implementation of each one must recursively invoke all children, but not add itself to the returned vector, and each subclass override it, and add itself to the returned vector. That's the blueprint.

Comment: @PaulSanders you should read the question, the problem is that I cannot make it `virtual` because C++ does not support `virtual template<>` functions.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ah, that sucks, but thank you.

Comment: I did, but, if you make it `virtual`, does it need to be a template?

Comment: @PaulSanders yes, I will give you an example: I have an `node` object of some `Node` subtype, and I want to get all its children, but only children of the type `NodeTwo` like this: `node->GetChildren<NodeTwo>()` you see the problem ?

Comment: OK.  I would look into CRTP to address this.  It lets you derive your various templates from a common base class template and the common functionality can go in there.  It will take you a day or two to get your head around it if you've not used it before, but it's a very cool trick.

Comment: I expect you have a fully broken design. Even if you can return "some data type", how a caller will handle it without the information which type the data has in runtime? If you the caller needs it, you have to store it somewhere in the data. And if this is needed, you can simply use std::variant or maybe std::any. But again: It looks like fully broken design! Everytime you store "some bunch of anything", there is something wrong!

Comment: @Klaus could you elaborate please? I do not understand what you mean in your comment at all sorry.

Comment: @PaulSanders OK, I looked into CRTP, but this also does not work for me, because if I want to store an object that derives from the CRTP, I need to know the derived type (template parameter), so this is useless, if I knew the most derived type, I wouldn't need virtual. EDIT: Sorry, I just realised I said I do not need it to be virtual, I was wrong just forgot to edit, I do need polymorphism.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but CRTP is, essentially, polymorphism for templates.  I doubt you've fully grasped it yet, so I'd try putting together something simple to get a better idea of how it works and what it can do (personally, I'd use an online compiler for this - I like Wandbox).  If you need to, you should then be in a position to ask a new, more tightly-focussed question to help move things on.  Don't forget to include a [mre], rather than separate bits of code.

Comment: @PaulSanders sorry for the notifications, I deleted multiple of my comments, I'm too tired and keep forgetting something everytime, I will sleep on it and maybe ask a new question tomorrow.

Comment: No worries, I do it too :)